# How to change word selection separator characters in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, selection

Depending on your system, the word separator characters change the way you can select/delete a word (e.g. by double clicking on it or using a key combination with your keyboard).

The fact is that I *hate* the default behavior of OSX.

For example:

Take the following line of code:

obj.attr1.innerAttr

If my cursor is at the end of the line and I press <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>backspace</kbd>, it will delete everything and not just `innerAttr`.

I only found some apps (like iTerm) which let you change the word selection separator characters.

Is there a way to change it for the whole system?

Answer (score 5):

[image]

The only difference between the two English options (at least in for ASCII characters) seems to be whether period and colon are treated as part of words.

Part of words:

- `'.:_` in Standard
- `'_` in English (United States, Computer)

Not part of the start or end of words:

- `` $+<=>^` `` in Standard
- `` $+<=>^` `` in English (United States, Computer)

Answer (score 5):

The answer by [user `](https://superuser.com/users/69039/%D8%98%D8%98%D8%98%D8%98) is correct for pre-osx-10.9 (I think).  However, in OS X 10.9 and later the System Preferences changed a bit. It now looks like this:

[image: Language & Region]

Comment: Apple keeps moving this around. This no longer works on 10.13. New solution `defaults write .GlobalPreferences AppleTextBreakLocale en_US_POSIX` via https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/124788/15378

Answer (score 3):

To the best of my knowledge, selection word separation is done on a per-application basis, not a system-wide basis. iTerm allows you to configure the characters, but that's an extremely unusual option; most applications use the predetermined defaults in the Cocoa and Carbon libraries, which are hard-coded, not drawn from a centralized preference setting.

Comment: Well, that's just too bad...

Comment: More importantly, iTerm's preference only affects selecting text in iTerm. It doesn't affect how tty applications move the cursor or edit words.

Comment: Mac is the least usable of the 3 major operating systems for programming. I have used Windows, Linux, and MacOS extensively over the past 5 years and I just can't stand Mac. Apple constantly changes how their system works to the point where SO and third party tools are almost always outdated.