# Can I specify double-click selection delimiters in Terminal.app?

Tags: macos, terminal.app, selection

In Mac OS X's Terminal.app, I'd like to set my own selection delimiters such that if I have the text foo.bar.baz and double click bar, only bar is selected.

Is this possible and if so how?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It would appear from [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/125011/mac-os-x-how-to-change-word-separator-characters) that it isn't configurable, at least system wide, and that configurable applications are rare. However, iTerm was mentioned as one that is.

Comment: To clarify: that question is unrelated to this one. That question is about changing how application programs like Emacs and Vim treat words. iTerm's word separator preference only affects selecting text with iTerm. Still, the answer to this question is that the selection separator is not directly configurable in Terminal. However, it's worth noting that Terminal uses the system-wide preference **System Preferences > Language & Text > Text > Word Break**, which users can change, but there probably aren't any available preference values that would help in this case.

Answer (score 37):

Shift + Command + double_click

From:
http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=2400559&start=15&tstart=0

Comment: Shift-Command-Double-Click is the anti-answer. It selects whole pathnames. This question is about how to restrict the selection to just part of a domain name or pathname.

Comment: @Chris The question asked how do I double click to select foo.bar.baz in the terminal.  Shift-Command-Double-Click works for that use case.

Comment: "…such that if I have the text foo.bar.baz and double click bar, _only bar_ is selected." [emph. Mine]

Comment: I don't this answered the original question, but it's exactly what I was looking for... now if only i could make this the default double-click behavior...

Comment: The only problem is now remaining using custom delimiters. And I think question is asked for that only.