# Mac OSX / Xcode, double click the word to select it, selects across dots and other characters

Tags: macos, xcode, selection, double-click

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Wrapping word configuration in mac](https://superuser.com/questions/242512/wrapping-word-configuration-in-mac)

I don't know if it's supposed to work like on Windows, but some apps like Chrome, Firefox are doing this as expected and some, like XCode or Text Edit not.

Example, double click on newRectangle word

`factory.newRectangle(320, 0, 1, 480)`

**Chrome, Firefox:** selects only newRectangle word.

**XCode, TextEdit:** selects all this: factory.newRectangle.

Is there a way to set that up?

Comment: I'd give 15 points to know why this question was rated -1.

Comment: Ok, looks like somebody else bumped it up to 1 point. Still no answers though.

Comment: FWIW, I get the chrome/firefox behavior in xcode 3.2.5 64bit os x 10.6.6

Comment: @roviuser See the linked topic. You probably have a different setting than Murgh.

Answer (score 0):

See the answer I gave on [this Superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/242512/wrapping-word-configuration-in-mac/242635#242635). Basically you need to set this up for all Cocoa applications (like XCode and TextEdit).

Yours, Asmus

Comment: Thanks for trying to help but it doesn't work with xCode. Still selects across dots.

Comment: Did you really restart XCode? Also: which version are you using? Because it works for me under XCode 3.2.5!

Comment: Yeah, I CMD-Q'd and reopened. I have 3.2.2 - 64 bit. Still selects across dots.