# How to change the default double click text separators?

Tags: macos, mac, google-chrome, selection

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Mac OS X: How to change word separator characters?](https://superuser.com/questions/125011/mac-os-x-how-to-change-word-separator-characters)
>   [Wrapping word configuration in mac](https://superuser.com/questions/242512/wrapping-word-configuration-in-mac)

I would like : to cause a different selection when text is double clicked.

Eg if in Chrome (beta v9, OSX Snow Leopard) I double click on the text define:superuser, and I click on the superuser part of that line, it should only select superuser, not the whole thing.

I wonder if this can be done!

Comment: Where do you want to change it? Mac OS X system-wide?

Comment: ...possible duplicate to [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/242512/wrapping-word-configuration-in-mac/242635#242635)

Comment: @Asmus that solution does not solve it sadly.

Comment: @Daniel don't really mind, as long as Chrome changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the default word break setting to English (United States, Computer).

[image]

The only difference between the two English options (at least for ASCII characters) seems to be whether period and colon are treated as part of words.

Part of words:

- `'.:_` in Standard
- `'_` in English (United States, Computer)

Not part of the start or end of words:

- `` $+<=>^` `` in Standard
- `` $+<=>^` `` in English (United States, Computer)

Comment: Thanks, though sadly define:text will still be selected in its entirety. However, define.text is now broken up.

Comment: Safari behavior is different depending on whether it's on a web page, a text area, or in the address bar.

Comment: How can I change it in Windows?